# Why am I getting the "!File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.<inserted text>\par<>./beamers.texl suspect you have forgotten a '}'" mistake

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,stmaryrd}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

%Declare graphics extensions
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %fuentes de LaTeX
\usetheme{Warsaw}  %Tema escogido en este ejemplo
\setbeamercovered{transparent} %Velos

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{ejemplo}{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definición}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}
\newtheorem{prueba}{Prueba}

\begin{document}

\title{Factorización en $Z_p$ y en $Z[x].$\\}
\subtitle{Parte I}
\author{{\bf Ing. Humberto H.R.}\\
        {Escuela de Matemática}\\
        {http://www.tec-digital.itcr.ac.cr/revistamatematica/}\\
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \date{Julio 2018}
\frame{\titlepage}

\section{ Primera Sección}

\begin{frame}{Título de este marco}

\end{frame}

\begin{Título de este marco}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing `}` after `\date{Julio 2018}`

Comment: Maybe the `}` should be before `\date`? It should probably also be `\begin{frame}{Título de este marco}` instead of `\begin{Título de este marco}`

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `}`-bracket behind `\vspace{0.5cm}`.
Furthermore (an additional error): `\begin{frame}{Título de este marco}` was missing the `{frame}` argument.

This is the working version:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,stmaryrd}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

%Declare graphics extensions
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %fuentes de LaTeX
\usetheme{Warsaw}  %Tema escogido en este ejemplo
\setbeamercovered{transparent} %Velos

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{ejemplo}{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definición}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}
\newtheorem{prueba}{Prueba}

\begin{document}

\title{Factorización en $Z_p$ y en $Z[x].$\\}
\subtitle{Parte I}
\author{{\bf Ing. Humberto H.R.}\\
        {Escuela de Matemática}\\
        {http://www.tec-digital.itcr.ac.cr/revistamatematica/}\\
        \vspace{0.5cm}}
\date{Julio 2018}
\frame{\titlepage}

\section{ Primera Sección}

\begin{frame}{Título de este marco}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Título de este marco}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Change footer to include short author name

However, the author is very long (it includes the Escuela and a link). The author appears in the footer again. Therefore it might be good to include a short title for the author like this:

```
\author[Ing. Humberto H.R.]{{\bf Ing. Humberto H.R.}\\
        {Escuela de Matemática}\\
        {http://www.tec-digital.itcr.ac.cr/revistamatematica/}\\
        \vspace{0.5cm}}
```